# Redirect everything to 404 except files in public folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How redirect everything inside `root`folder to 404, except files in `root/public` folder? Directory listing must be disabled everywhere and `.htaccess`redirected to 404 as well. It's possible to make that with one `.htaccess` file?

Currently i have `Redirect 404 /` in `root`, but when trying to access `.htaccess`, it's forbidden. Thanks

Comment: Why are those files there in the first place? It looks like you want root/public to be your actual root.

Comment: i want enable access to files in root/public (index.php, register.php) and disable access to everything else in root (classes, views)

Comment: I mean, I think this is not something that you want to solve through .htaccess. Instead, if you tell your server that root/public *is* your document root, people can only access stuff in that folder. You can do it using .htaccess, but it seems to me you're just building a work-around for an earlier misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect everything inside rootfolder to 404, except files in root/public folder ,you   can use the following Rule in your `/root/.htaccess` .

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !public - [R=404,L]
```

and to disable directory listing for all folder/subfolders, add this line to your `/root/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```